# Is there a way to take variables and add them as columns after a left join in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have 2 tables:
 table A:

```
| ID |  class1     |  class2 | class3 |  class4 |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------+
|  1 |  ABC123     |  23     | C123   | BC123   | 
|  2 |  DEF465     |  65     | F465   | EF465   | 
|  3 |  GHI789     |  89     | I789   | HI789   |
|  4 |  JKL132     |  32     | L132   | KL132   |
|  5 |  MNO456     |  56     | O456   | NO456   |
```

and Table B:

```
| ID |  class_desc |     text   | 
+----+-------------+------------+
|  1 |  ABC123     |  "foo"     |  
|  2 |  23         |  "foo b"   |
|  3 |  C123       |  "foo bar" | 
|  4 |  BC123      |  "foo-bar" | 
|  5 |  DEF465     |  "bar"     | 
|  6 |  65         |  "bar f"   | 
|  7 |  F465       |  "bar foo" | 
|  7 |  EF465      |  "bar-foo" | 
etc...
```

I want to do a left join where I get a Table like Table C:

```
| ID |  class1  |  class2 | class3 |  class4 | class_1_desc | class_2_desc | class_3_desc| class_4_desc|
+----+----------+---------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |  ABC123  |  23     | C123   | BC123   | "foo"        |"foo b"       |"foo bar"    |"foo-bar"    |
|  2 |  DEF465  |  65     | F465   | EF465   | "bar"        |"bar f"       |"bar foo"    |  "bar-foo"  |
|  3 |  GHI789  |  89     | I789   | HI789   | etc...
|  4 |  JKL132  |  32     | L132   | KL132   |
|  5 |  MNO456  |  56     | O456   | NO456   |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that 'etc' is rarely helpful in this situation. Instead, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join 4 times:

```
select 
    ta.*,
    tb1.text class_1_desc,
    tb2.text class_2_desc,
    tb3.text class_3_desc,
    tb4.text class_4_desc
from tableA ta
inner join tableB tb1 on tb1.class_desc = ta.class1
inner join tableB tb2 on tb2.class_desc = ta.class2
inner join tableB tb3 on tb3.class_desc = ta.class3
inner join tableB tb4 on tb4.class_desc = ta.class4
```

If there is a possibility that one of the `class`es declared in `tableA` does not exist in `tableB`, then you want `left join`s instead of `inner join`s.

If you actually want to create a new table, say `tableC`, with the results of the query, then you can use the `create table ... as select` syntax:

```
create table tableC as
select 
    ta.*,
    tb1.text class_1_desc,
    tb2.text class_2_desc,
    tb3.text class_3_desc,
    tb4.text class_4_desc
from tableA ta
inner join tableB tb1 on tb1.class_desc = ta.class1
inner join tableB tb2 on tb2.class_desc = ta.class2
inner join tableB tb3 on tb3.class_desc = ta.class3
inner join tableB tb4 on tb4.class_desc = ta.class4
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02a13c1cee025bfabd708ec11a9e4ae0)** (using `left join`s, since your sample data is incomplete):

```
ID | class1 | class2 | class3 | class4 | class_1_desc | class_2_desc | class_3_desc | class_4_desc
-: | :----- | -----: | :----- | :----- | :----------- | :----------- | :----------- | :-----------
 1 | ABC123 |     23 | C123   | BC123  | foo          | foo b        | foo bar      | foo-bar     
 2 | DEF465 |     65 | F465   | EF465  | bar          | bar f        | bar foo      | null        
 3 | GHI789 |     89 | I789   | HI789  | null         | null         | null         | null        
 4 | JKL132 |     32 | L132   | KL132  | null         | null         | null         | null        
 5 | MNO456 |     56 | O456   | NO456  | null         | null         | null         | null
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want multiple `left join`s:

```
select a.*,
       b1.text as text_1,
       b2.text as text_2,
       b3.text as text_3,
       b4.text as text_4
from a left join
     b b1
     on b1.class_desc = a.class1 left join
     b b2
     on b2.class_desc = a.class2 left join
     b b3
     on b3.class_desc = a.class3 left join
     b b4
     on b4.class_desc = a.class4;
```